# PHP Woocommerce Minimum Amount of Products in Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a coffee buying site and I am having an issue of trying to make sure buyers can only complete checkout if they have the minimum amount of products.

For example, if Product A is in the cart then there must be a minimum of product category C for them to check out.

There are 4 separate brewers with different minimums that need to have this function. I have searched for plug-ins cannot find one that does what I need.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

I've tried using this code

```
// Set minimum quantity per product before checking out
if(woo_in_cart($5579)) {
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_qty_per_product' );
function spyr_set_min_qty_per_product() {
// Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {  
    global $woocommerce;

    // Product Id and Min. Quantities per Product
    $product_min_qty = array( 
        array( 'id' => 91, 'min' => 4),
    );

    // Will increment
    $i = 0;
    // Will hold information about products that have not
    // met the minimum order quantity
    $bad_products = array();

    // Loop through the products in the Cart
    foreach( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product_in_cart ) {
        // Loop through our minimum order quantities per product
        foreach( $product_min_qty as $product_to_test ) {
            // If we can match the product ID to the ID set on the minimum required array
            if( $product_to_test['id'] == $product_in_cart['product_id'] ) {
                // If the quantity required is less than than the quantity in the cart now
                if( $product_in_cart['quantity'] < $product_to_test['min'] ) {
                    // Get the product ID
                    $bad_products[$i]['id'] = $product_in_cart['product_id'];
                    // Get the Product quantity already in the cart for this product
                    $bad_products[$i]['in_cart'] = $product_in_cart['quantity'];
                    // Get the minimum required for this product
                    $bad_products[$i]['min_req'] = $product_to_test['min'];
                }
            }
        }
        // Increment $i
        $i++;
    }

    // Time to build our error message to inform the customer
    // About the minimum quantity per order.
    if( is_array( $bad_products) && count( $bad_products ) > 1 ) {
        // Lets begin building our message
        $message = '<strong>A minimum quantity of the choosen Brewer has not been met. (Kuerig 140 Reqiures A Minimum of 4 Boxes to Order)<br />(Kuerig 150 Reqiures A Minimum of 8 Boxes to Order)<br />(Kuerig K3000SE Reqiures A Minimum of 12 Boxes to Order)<br />(Kuerig Bolt Carafe Reqiures A Minimum of 10 Boxes to Order)</strong><br />';
        foreach( $bad_products as $bad_product ) {
            // Append to the current message
            $message .= get_the_title( $bad_product['id'] ) .' requires a minimum quantity of '
                     . $bad_product['min_req'] 
                     .'. You currently have: '. $bad_product['in_cart'] .'.<br />';
        }
        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I think you need to make kind of different packs, maybe using variable products (options). Like this you avoid the minimum complex amount based on this special products. If not It's a real development.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation LoicTheAztec. There are about 100 different coffee boxes for a person to choose from. I don't think making different packs is what my goal is.

Comment: Would [min/max quantities](https://woocommerce.com/products/minmax-quantities/) work? Three things, 1. `$woocommerce` should be replaced with `WC()` and 2. what is `woo_in_cart($5579)`? and `if(woo_in_cart($5579)) {` should be *inside* the `add_action()` callback. Based on the code you've shown, it will *never* run because that will always be false.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback helgatheviking. I am not experienced in PHP coding much less setting up woocommerce scripts. The 5589 is the product id for a coffee brewer. I tried using the min/max quantities but I am not grouping any products. Every customer should be able to choose any combo of coffee as long as the minimum is reached.  I made some of the suggested edits and didn't break the site this time but the error warning never came up